# How do I disable Private Access Tokens in Safari Desktop?

Tags: safari, desktop, ventura

On iOS 16, I disable Private Access Token (PAT) in *Settings > Apple ID > Password & Security > Automatic Verification*. How do I achieve this for Safari Desktop?

On macOS Ventura 13.5 (22G74), I have not found a corresponding function.

**Update/Solution:** For the setting to take effect, the device must be restarted.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213449

Comment: @LincD.: Can anyone confirm this? For me (Safari Desktop 16.6), the demo https://patdemo-o.edgecompute.app/ continues to report that I have activated PAT, despite disabled option.